# How to manage incomparable movement speeds in combat?

Tags: combat, movement, anima-beyond-fantasy

I'm playing a Shadow character in a campaign which is running for 2 year.
Our party has reached a great amount gnosi (27), and we are all level 13.

The main features of my character is agility and speed movement.
He can move 150m/turn at full speed (even more with Ki agumentation) and I cannot understand how to manage this in combat situation.

If he moves at full speed he can easily get out of close combat range.

If he uses Ki agumentation he can moves up to 25Km/turn at full speed, this should allow to enter/exit combat range with a simple partial movement (passive action).

How should I manage this great difference in speed during combat situations?

**Edit 1:**

@IgneusJotunn the rest of the party moves normally (10 to 20 m/turn); they have other kind of special abilities. We all perform more or less the same number of attacks per turn (this number is determinated by the attack ability and not by the movement speed).

Also the enemies usually have other kind of peculiarities, so in normal situation my character goes as slow as he can in order to remain with the party. But a battle is a battle, so he uses all his power and moves as fast as he can.
He has an Ars Magnus which allow him to appear at the back of his opponent and perform some attacks.

A problem is when someone perform an area attack, usually the range of the attach is much lower than his movement speed, so it should be able to evade them simply moving out of the range instead of performing a Dodge roll. But this seems to be a bit overpower because will ensure immunity to any kind of attacks simply by getting out of the range.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Here's a +1 to get you going. BTW, how long is a turn?  Because if you break the speed of sound (340.29m/s), it would have immense impact on the combat...

Comment: Thank you @Sardathrion. The turn is 3 seconds. He will surely break the speed of sound.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the flash comics and seeing how he makes use of his speed.

Comment: Can he attack more than once ? Taking anime for inspiration, I can see your character knocking an enemy back a few meters, then moving to catch him there and attack again, *a la* Dragon Ball.

Comment: @Nigralbus yes he can but it's unrelated to the speed movement.

Comment: How fast does the rest of the party move? Anywhere close to that speed? Does your character take more turns than they do?

Comment: One question: He can move up to 25 km/turn but can he accelerate to that speed in a single turn? If his acceleration is limited, that should change things a lot.

Comment: By the way, that maximum speed is Mach 25 at sea level. A 70kg non aerodynamic object moving at that speed would be subject to tremendous forces, and it would wreak havoc :)

Comment: Presumably, half of the training is in how to use Ki to counter those forces and slip through the air. Yay for ubiquitous magic in a setting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If Anima allows you to move/attack/move, then you can consider yourself the equivalent of a sniper with melee attacks. The enemy would have to figure out tactics that can trap/hurt you when you get in range. These might be readying to receive a charge or setting up tripwires.

In your case the Dodge skill would represent his ability to react to those area attacks in an appropriate manner. If he's there at the moment of the attack, that's where he is. The attacker has been leading him with a rocket launcher or he's just tripped a mine or whatever.

### Why this makes sense

The logical reasoning behind this is that you have the ability to run very fast but it doesn't translate into making your arms move incredibly fast or increase the number of attacks you can have. For an example, check out the landlady chase scene in Kung Fu Hustle (which you should have watched as source material anyway :P).

### For you

If you're in open spaces, don't worry about staying on the map. Hit and run tactics are what you've chosen to focus on.

### For your GM

It isn't a problem that one of your players doesn't have to be on the map to attack people. He's constantly at long range. So what. It just means that to defeat him, people are going to have to find some interesting counters to his tactics. Counterattacks, land mines, slowing auras, tight quarters and so on.

Those will validate his choices and add challenge to the game.

Comment: I've checked the rulebook and it allows you to split the movement in order to move/attack/move. The only requirement is that the total moved lenght is <= 1/4 of total movement.

Comment: +1.  Anima is all about cool 'unstoppable' powers and finding a counter to them.

Answer (score 1):

Anima is not very known for its regards to physics... the setting runs on rool of cool, so things like acceleration, sound barrier and such are hand waved. At gnosis 27 you are barely human anyway so you can do inhuman things. You are also capable of inhuman things thanks to inhumanity and zen (that you need to do this stuff).

So yeah, a shadow level 13 with infinium (the ars magnus that lets you appear at the back of people is infinium right? I don’t have the book at hand…) can appear at your back from no were, attack, and move out the length of your sword. In the same turn. Before you have a chance to blink. It’s a freaking shadow level 13, you will be glad if you can see him do that.

If you must combat that, you should treat it like a ranged character that happens to attack with melee weapons, but most of the time is at ranged distance. As mentioned you still have problems with couter-attacks, changing terrain, like landmines, but also other stuff like flying things, walls (not very much) or other things grabbing you (with your dex its going to be hard but possible).

In Anima at that levels you do crazy stuff all the time, I don’t see any problem in move-attack-move (beware of people charging at you!).

That said, I understand that a person moving at 25 km/h should not be hit easily. But the rules more or less say that when your turn comes, all other people/monsters/things are stationary when it comes to hit them. I mean in a ‘real’ combat a fighter that moves incredibly more quickly than other can keep a distance with no problem, in Anima this is not the case, the same rules that let you move-attack-move, let other people move-attack you (or charge you) even if in more ‘realistic’ settings they would have no chance in touching you.

Comment: You are right, all our party is barely human. Concerning the last paragraph: If I act first I can move/attack/move out of any melee range. If I'm not the first, and I'm in range a PNG can attack me. But my GM said that I had to perform some obscure acrobatics check to escape an engaged fight.

Comment: I think that is in the rules, when engaged in close combat, if you want to leave the combat you must do an acrobatic check, that is a very DnDesque thing, but I think I remember reading it in some manual. So, yes, you will probably need an acrobatic check in your move/attack/move sequence, I do not think this roll has a penalty for additional action (could be, though). But at level 13 this roll should be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

> A problem is when someone perform an area attack, usually the range of
>   the attach is much lower than his movement speed, so it should be able
>   to evade them simply moving out of the range instead of performing a
>   Dodge roll. But this seems to be a bit overpower because will ensure
>   immunity to any kind of attacks simply by getting out of the range.

I would interpret a failed dodge roll as "did not notice the attack in time to move fast out of the area" and a successful dodge roll as "avoided the attack, possibly by moving out of the area".

Comment: In fact your movement speed  is important when dodging an area attack. I remmember that you recive a negative if you are not able to run the distance required to escape the area...